# VSCode Extension that Executes terminal command

Tags: terminal, vscode-extensions, cpu-architecture, amd-processor, ubuntu-22.04

Trying to write an extension that executes the terminal command.

For example:
if I execute the `sensors` command in the terminal, it will show the CPU temperature. I want to create a command that prints this information into the terminal upon activation.

I have tried by placing it with registercommand like following.

```
let d = vscode.commands.registerCommand(sensors);
context.subscriptions.push(d);
```

Does anyone know where to put these type of terminal commands?

Environment:
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

AMD Ryzen 3

Comment: putting the solution with code based on@Mike Lischke's answer in the answer section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to use Node.js' child_process module, run the sensor command in a separate process with this, read the output and print that in an output channel in VS Code.

Answer (score 1):

Used child_process to execute the terminal command from extension (One click output)

```
exec('sensors', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if(error){
        console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
        return;
    }
    if(stderr){
        console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found a far convenient way of executing terminal commands from a VS Code Extension. It is combining the createTerminal() function and sendText() function.

```
let cmd = vscode.window.createTerminal();   //creates a terminal with a backing shell process
cmd.sendText("sensors");                    //write the inteded terminal commmand inside the "" and sendText() will pass it to the created terminal
cmd.show();                                 //shows the command execution output
```